# Avoid unwanted form submission

Tags: javascript, html, forms, submit

I have a problem when I want to use a button to switch into another page, and another button to just close the window (a popup)

No matter which button I click, the form submits. What can I do to avoid this (apart from switching the `</form>` between the two buttons) ?

The code:

```
<form action="name.php" method="post">
                <input type="hidden" name="number" value="<?php echo $id;?>">
                <input type="hidden" name="position" value="<?php echo $pos;?>">
<button type="submit">Yes</button> <button onclick="window.close()">No</button>
</form>
```

Comment: I would not use a `<button>` tag to close the window. Use anchor link and javascript. This would be more semantically appropriate.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can add `return false` to the end of the onclick for your second button:

```
<button onclick="window.close(); return false">
```